# Magento 2 cannot set searchCriteria to rest api for categories

Tags: magento2, category, rest-api, search-criteria

Tried using the url below to get all sub-categories, but it retuns all categories without filtering.

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/rest/V1/categories/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=level&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=3&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Is categories not support searchCriteria?

Comment: These search criteria applies to all API classes/interfaces which implements the method: getList(\Magento\Framework\)

Comment: Thanks,  CategoryManagementInterface does not have getList() function, it has only getTree() which does not support searchCriteria.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314994/get-the-value-of-sales-order-address-table-custom-column-value-in-rest-v1-orders?noredirect=1#comment452389_314994 if you still look for an answer

Answer (score 0):

yes it will give you all category what you have to do now you have to filter in response Code