# Call 3rd party rest api with basic auth username and password

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am calling 3rd party API in my postman I have choose Authorization as basic auth and passing username and password.

I am using Zend Client in magento 2 to send request now bt I set headers like this as basic auth it is throwing me error as : Authorization error because I havent passed username and password in basic auth

Can anyone tell me how to pass that in magento 2 while calling api

Here is my code:

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Zend\Http\Client $zendClient
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->zendClient = $zendClient;
    }


$this->zendClient->setHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Basic Auth AC687732356d7cc641b4**username a9bfa6d5f473db2e346e1*pwd***',
            ]);
```

Comment: you might want to check the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314994/get-the-value-of-sales-order-address-table-custom-column-value-in-rest-v1-orders/315367#315367